# Refreshing list in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am trying to create a list of movies with ListFragment (by following [this tutorial](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/)). In the fragment I have a Loader and an AsyncTaskLoader which downloads information from a web service. The AsyncTaskLoader downloads all information correctly and the method "onLoadFinished" is executed correctly.
In onLoadFinished I call a function in the listadapter to set the new data and then call notifyDataSetChanged(). 
I know that the data in the adapter is set correctly (log statement will print the title of the first movie from the adapter-class), but the listview won't show anything.
However, if I supply a list of movies to the constructor of the adapter it works.

**Code for the ListFragment (not all code, only the code that sets up the adapter, loader etc):**

```
public class MovieListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<MovieInformation>>{

  public static final String TAG = "MovieListFragment";
  private SimpleMovieListAdapter listAdapter;

  public MovieListFragment() {
  }

  @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("DataListFragment.onActivityCreated");

    setEmptyText("No results");
    listAdapter = new SimpleMovieListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.movie_list_row_layout);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    setListShown(false);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

**The loader:**

```
public Loader<List<MovieInformation>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    return new MovieListDownloader(getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<MovieInformation>> arg0,
        List<MovieInformation> data) {
    listAdapter.setData(data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    Log.d(TAG, ("length is: " + data.size()));
    setListShown(true);
    /*
    if(data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
        setListShown(true);
    }else{
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
    */
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<MovieInformation>> arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
    listAdapter.setData(null);
}
```

**The Adapter:**

```
public class SimpleMovieListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieInformation> {
  private static final String TAG = "SimpleMovieListAdapter";
  private Context context;
  private List<MovieInformation> movies;
  ImageLoader imageLoader;

  public SimpleMovieListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<MovieInformation> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      this.context = context;
      this.movies = objects;
      imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();

  }
  public SimpleMovieListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
      super(context, textViewResourceId);
      this.context = context;
      imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();
  }

  public void setData(List<MovieInformation> movies){
      this.movies = movies;

      //This log statement will display the title of the first movie in the set (so the list of movies is updated correctly)
      Log.d(TAG, this.movies.get(0).getTitle());
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Log.d(TAG, ("GetView position" + position));
    View rowView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row_layout, parent, false);
    } else {
        rowView = convertView;
    }

    TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.movie_list_title);
    TextView yearText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.movie_list_year);
    TextView voteAverageText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.movie_list_vote_average);
    ImageView posterView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.movie_list_poster);
    titleText.setText(movies.get(position).getTitle());
    yearText.setText("(" + movies.get(position).getYear() + ")");
    voteAverageText.setText(movies.get(position).getFormattedRatingAndVoteCount() + " " + 
            context.getString(R.string.movie_info_votes) + ")");


    imageLoader.displayImage((MyApplication.POSTER_SOURCE_ADDRESS + 
            movies.get(position).getPosterPath()), posterView, MyApplication.options);

    return rowView;
}
}
```

**Edit 1**
I found a solution right after posting the question, but I dont think it's a "nice" solution.
In onLoadFinished, instead of passing the data to the adapter.setData() I simply created a new adapter (passing in the array of movies to the constructor) and then called setListAdapter() again. It works, but it feels like an ugly solution (creating and setting new adapters probably would consume more resources?).

**Edit 2**
Just to clarify something about setData in the adapterclass:
After adding all the data to the array (this.movies) I loop through the entire array and print the title for each movie with a Log-statement. So the data is stored in the arraylist in the adapterclass after calling setData, but the listview is still not populated with data.

```
public void setData(List<MovieInformation> movies){
         this.movies = movies;

    if(movies != null){
        this.movies.addAll(movies);

    }
    for(MovieInformation m : this.movies){
        Log.d(TAG, ("movie : " + this.movies.indexOf(m) + " " + this.movies.get(this.movies.indexOf(m)).getTitle()));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

instead of doing

```
  public void setData(List<MovieInformation> movies){
      this.movies = movies;

      //This log statement will display the title of the first movie in the set (so the list of movies is updated correctly)
      Log.d(TAG, this.movies.get(0).getTitle());
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

change this line  `this.movies = movies;`

to

```
this.movies.clear(); 
if(movies!=null){

this.movies.addAll(movies); }

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT**

When you are creating your listview you are using this constructor:

```
  public SimpleMovieListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId){
  super(context, textViewResourceId);
  this.context = context;
  imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

}

you are not creating a new instance of your data list
try adding the line : `this.movies = new ArrayList<MovieInformation>();`

and add the other fix, it should work

**EDIT #2**
change your adapter to extend base adapter, change your constructors like this:

and update the line where you create a new adapter accordingly

```
public class SimpleMovieListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private static final String TAG = "SimpleMovieListAdapter";
  private Context context;
  private List<MovieInformation> movies;
  ImageLoader imageLoader;

  public SimpleMovieListAdapter(Context context, List<MovieInformation> objects) {
      this.context = context;
      this.movies = objects;
      imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();

  }
  public SimpleMovieListAdapter(Context context){
      this.context = context;
      this.movies = new ArrayList<MovieInformation>();
      imageLoader =  ImageLoader.getInstance();
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the list will still not refresh. The movies will be added to the ArrayList in the Adapter-class, but getView is never executed (so the rows are never created)

Comment: What's with the null check for movies one line after you have dereferenced it without a null check?

Comment: there is some place where he does setData(null), it may get NPE if you do this.movies.addAll(null)

Comment: @Skrot try this change

Comment: I tried your new suggestion to create the instance of the arraylist, still no improvement. The list that is passed to "setData" is stored correct in the ArrayList when using this.movies.addAll(movies). By looping through the arraylist and printing the title for every movie I know that the data is stored in the adapter.

Comment: show me your getView - are you sure it is not getting called?

Comment: Lena that depends. If I use the constructor with 3 arguments and pass the data directly to the adapter it gets called and the list is populated with data. But if i use the constructor with 2 arguments (like I am trying to do) and then call setData getView is not called. I'll update the main post with my getView.

Comment: I think your problem is the fact that you are using ArrayList adapter - change the adapter type to BaseAdapter and your problem should be fixed, if you read the API of the ArrayListAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html you will see that it behaves a bit differently than what you would expect

Comment: @Skrot since you are not using the actual functionality of the ArrayList adapter in your getview, i suggest you use the BaseAdapter instead

Comment: Ah, you are right :). I've misunderstood how the ArrayList adapter works. I removed my own arraylist and add all objects to the "built in" array. I also replaced "this.movies.get(poisition)" in getView with getItem(position), so now it works. Thank you Lena! :)